# conf/hadoop-env.sh file opening in readonly mode

Tags: file-permissions, chown

Well i am trying to configure a single node cluster hadoop.Now i have created a user hadoop alonside  and i have installed hadoop in my usr/local/hadoop directory.

Then i have done the following commands

```
chown hadoop:hadoop hadoop hadoop-1.0.4
ln -s hadoop-1.04/ hadoop.
```

as a result when i do ls -l
it shows the following

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4096 Jun 16  2012 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4096 Jun 16  2012 etc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4096 Jun 16  2012 games
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root     13 Apr 16 13:20 hadoop -> hadoop-1.0.4/
drwxr-xr-x 13 hadoop hadoop 4096 Oct  3  2012 hadoop-1.0.4
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4096 Jun 16  2012 include
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root   4096 Jun 16  2012 lib
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root      9 Aug 22  2012 man -> share/man
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4096 Jun 16  2012 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  6 root   root   4096 Jun 16  2012 share
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4096 Jun 16  2012 src
```

so hadoop 1.0.4 has hadoop as usergroup.

Now when i am entring my hadoop group using

su -hadoop

so i can change my conf/hadoop-env.sh file but it is not happening

hadoop@iu1:/usr/local$  vi conf/hadoop-env.sh

the file opens in readonly mode

i think it should be editable mode

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `chown` recursively:

```
chown -R hadoop:hadoop hadoop hadoop-1.0.4
```

To verify file permissions do

```
ls -l /usr/local/hadoop/conf/
```